# How to force a reload of ReactJS Relay Modern data (force fetch)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relay, relaymodern

Consider the following ReactJS component with Relay Modern:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { graphql } from "react-relay";
import { QueryRenderer } from "react-relay";

import environment from "../../relay/environment";

const CustomersQuery = graphql`
    query CustomersQuery($versionId: ID!) {
        viewer {
            customers {
                id
                name
            }
        }
    }
`;

class Customers extends Component {

    handleRefresh = () => {
        /// ???? ///
        How to force relay to refetch data here ?
        /// ???? ///
    };

    getCustomer = (customer) => {
        return (
                <div>
                    <p>Customer Data:</p>
                    <p>Id: {customer.id}</p>
                    <p>Name: {customer.name}</p>
                </div>
                );
    }

    handleContent = props => {
        let customers = props.viewer.customers.map(customer => {
            return this.getCustomer(customer);
        });

        return (
                <div>
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.handleRefresh}>
                        Reload Screen
                    </button>
                    {customers}
                </div>
        );
    };

    render = () => {
        return (
            <QueryRenderer
                environment={environment}
                query={this.props.query}
                render={({ error, props }) => {
                    if (error) {
                        throw new error;
                    } else if (props) {
                        return this.handleContent(props);
                    }

                    return <p>>Loading...</p>;
                }}
            />
        );
    };
}

export default Customers;
```

What is the correct way to force the component to reload Relay data inside `handleRefresh` handler ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<QueryRenderer
    environment={environment}
    query={graphql`
    query  MyQuery  
    {  
      {  
        id                
        name                  
        caption                  
        url              
      }       
    `}
    variables={{isUpdate: this.state.isUpdate}} //Change the state in case you want latest response, this variable will be ignored at the server
    render={({error, props}) => {

        if (error) {
           console.error(error);
           return <div>Error!</div>;
        }
        if (!props) {
           return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        console.log("response from server --->" , JSON.stringify(props))
        return <div></div>
        }}
/>
```

You can add add a parameter in the api call and pass the state to that parameter , change the state to get the latest response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you extract your handleContent to a new component and use the createRefetchContainer HOC from relay. Then relay will inject a prop you can use to trigger refetch like: props.relay.refetch(...)

see [relay docs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/refetch-container.html)